# Filter on request type in chrome dev tools (Network tab)

Tags: google-chrome, web-development

In previous versions of Chrome I've had a buttom toolbar in which I could filter on different kinds of requests.

It's the one shown here:

[image]

I can however not see it anymore. To my knowledge, I've not hidden it but it has disappeared in an update. How can I get it back?

Comment: Duplicates [the same question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637278/is-there-a-way-to-filter-network-requests-using-google-chrome-developer-tools).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To filter requests by type, click the "Filter" icon ([image])

[image: Filtering in Chrome Developer Tools]

Answer (score 7):

Open dev tools, click on the filter icon, then you can type parameters like, to filter certain request types.

```
method:POST
```

example:

[image]